# Azure Event Hub to Stream Analytics with Partitions

Tags: azure, partitioning, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

[Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-overview/) states that:

> Partitions are a data organization mechanism and are more related to the degree of downstream parallelism required in consuming applications than to Event Hubs throughput.

Assuming that the only consumer of the `EventHubClient` is **Azure Stream Analytics**, is it relevant to configure a series of `Partitions` as input to the **Stream Analytics** job?

For example, if the **Stream Analytics** job is configured to scale to 6 `Streaming Units`, will configuring the `EventHubClient`, that loads the events, to leverage 6 `Partitions`, effect 6 parallel streams of input?

Or, are `Partitions` even relevant when the only consuming client is a **Stream Analytics** job?

Answer (score 0):

The 6 Streaming units has nothing to do with the EventHubclient, it is relevant to the #partitions you configured in ASA job

Comment: What is the optimal way to configure EventHubClient to effect a degree of parallelism that reflects the #partitions in the ASA job?